# Differential Equation using finite difference method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods

I am working on the following question

$$y''+8(\sin^2 \pi y) y=0$$
where the initial conditions are $$y(0) = y(1) = 1$$

Now by the finite difference method i have made the substitution for $y''$

Rewriting the following equation i get the following:-

$$\frac{ y_{i+1} -2y_i  + y_{i-1} }{h^2}$$

Now we obtain the following

$$\frac{ y_{i+1} -2y_i  + y_{i-1} }{h^2} + 8(\sin^2\pi y_i)y_i = 0$$

I am not sure how to handle the second part of the equation and break it down my values of $i = 1,2$. Therefore i need to get two simultaneous equations to solve but this expression Im not sure how to break it down into to generate my equations can anyone help me?

Comment: Finite difference method convert **linear** ordinary differential equations (ODE) or non-linear partial differential equations (PDE) into a system of equations that can be solved by matrix algebra techniques...

Comment: Yes I understand that Im just trying to break down the following expression $8(sin^2y_i)y_i$ as this is in terms of $y_i$ @AntonVrdoljak

Comment: Generally speaking you have a nonlinear function from $\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ which you can solve numerically e.g. by Newtons method.